# How to await for the first k futures?

Tags: rust, async-await

Say we have n servers, and we only need k < n responses .

I understand futures::join_all can be used to wait for all n futures, but I want my program finish waiting after k responses.

Is there something similar to join_all that I can use to wait for the first k responses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [streams](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) (async iterators) for this. You can use [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/futures_unordered/struct.FuturesUnordered.html) as an unordered collection of futures, which can be used as a stream where you get each future's result in the order they complete. Then you can combine this with [`.take(n)`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.take) to only take the first `n` items of the stream, and then [`.collect::<Vec<_>>()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/prelude/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.collect) to wait for the stream to finish and collect the results in a `Vec`:

```rust
use futures::prelude::*;
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;

let futures = vec![
    // assume `f(n, t)` = sleep for `t` millis, then return `n`
    f(1, 1000),
    f(2, 10),
    f(3, 105),
    f(4, 40),
    f(5, 70),
    f(6, 270),
];

// create unordered collection of futures
let futures = futures.into_iter().collect::<FuturesUnordered<_>>();

// use collection as a stream, await only first 4 futures to complete
let first_4 = futures.take(4).collect::<Vec<_>>().await;

// note: any remaining futures will be cancelled automatically when the
// stream is consumed

// check with expected result, based on the order of completion
assert_eq!(first_4, vec![2, 4, 5, 3]);
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=785f0327d8e6b6f0cd0127d592db8808)

---

**Edit:** If you want to also get the index of completed the future, you can use this:

```rust
// create unordered collection of futures with indices
let futures = futures
        .into_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, fut)| fut.map(move |res| (i, res)))
        .collect::<FuturesUnordered<_>>()
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f360b3c0c6783cf7bdfd50f907a7f59f)

Comment: This is a simpler way of doing it too. nice!

Comment: Awesome, thanks Frxstrem!

I also care about which index's are the first to finish, but I'm going to return a tuple with (i, result).

Comment: @F.Chen I've updated my answer with a small snippet showing how you can include the indices as well.

Comment: But this example breaks multi-threading completely if you assume sleeping for `t` in that `async` function. If you measure the execution time you will see that it takes the sum of all sleeps to complete the futures. Whereas it should actually take the longest of those

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is anything built for this purpose. Perhaps you can do this with `Stream`s or `Channel`s, but the [`join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.15/src/futures_util/future/join_all.rs.html#78-81) implementation isn't *too* complicated. I've modified it so that it only waits for `n` results:

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};

use futures::future::MaybeDone; // 0.3.15

fn iter_pin_mut<T>(slice: Pin<&mut [T]>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Pin<&mut T>> {
    // Safety: `std` _could_ make this unsound if it were to decide Pin's
    // invariants aren't required to transmit through slices. Otherwise this has
    // the same safety as a normal field pin projection.
    //
    // Copied from `futures` implementation of `join_all`.
    unsafe { slice.get_unchecked_mut() }.iter_mut().map(|t| unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(t) })
}

#[must_use = "futures do nothing unless you `.await` or poll them"]
pub struct JoinSome<F>
where
    F: Future,
{
    elems: Pin<Box<[MaybeDone<F>]>>,
    count: usize,
}

/// Will wait for at least `n` futures to complete. More may be returned if
/// multiple resolve around the same time.
///
/// # Panics
///
/// Will panic if iterator doesn't contain at least `n` futures.
pub fn join_some<I>(i: I, n: usize) -> JoinSome<I::Item>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Future,
{
    let elems: Box<[_]> = i.into_iter().map(MaybeDone::Future).collect();
    assert!(elems.len() >= n);
    JoinSome { elems: elems.into(), count: n }
}

impl<F> Future for JoinSome<F>
where
    F: Future,
{
    type Output = Vec<F::Output>;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let mut num_done = 0;

        for elem in iter_pin_mut(self.elems.as_mut()) {
            if !elem.poll(cx).is_pending() {
                num_done += 1;
            }
        }

        if num_done >= self.count {
            let mut elems = std::mem::replace(&mut self.elems, Box::pin([]));
            let result = iter_pin_mut(elems.as_mut()).filter_map(|e| e.take_output()).collect();
            Poll::Ready(result)
        } else {
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

I've added documentation in the source that explains its behavior. You can see that it works with this simple test program:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    use std::time::{Instant, Duration};
    use tokio::time::sleep;

    let futures = vec![
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)),
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)),
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(3)),
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(4)),
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)),
    ];
    
    let now = Instant::now();
    let some = join_some(futures, 3).await;
    let elapsed = now.elapsed();
    
    println!("{} results in {:.2?}", some.len(), elapsed);
}
```

```
3 results in 3.00s seconds
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=510d0b8a82306d472e972ac50f02803f).

Comment: Nice impl, it is actually surprising it do not exist per se in futures. They have join_n till join_5. It could be worth to create a PR to add this ;)